# NSStatusItem too short, text cut off

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-yosemite

I have a status item:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSStatusItem* item;
```

That I create this way:

```
item=[[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength: NSVariableStatusItemLength];
item.menu= self.menu;
item.image= icon;
item.highlightMode= YES;
```

The icon is 20x20, and other than the icon I am also setting the attributed title:

```
NSDictionary* attr= @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [controller color],
                       NSFontAttributeName : [NSFont userFontOfSize: 12.5]};
item.attributedTitle=[[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString: @"12190" 
                                                attributes: attr];
```

The problem is that the status bar is still getting cut off:

[image]

It should display the whole number, but it gets cut off from the digit '9'. I wrote this application when there was still OS X 10.8, and the text was not getting cut. If I am not mistaken it's doing only with OS X 10.10.

Comment: It looks like 'attributedTitle' has been depreciated in 10.10. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSStatusItem_Class/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue with setting NSStatusItem title property. It came up when I went from an empty text to a nonempty text in the `item.title` value. When the title was changed the second time the text cut off was fixed. For me the solution was to set the `item.title` twice when the previous value was an empty string.

Example code:

```
NSString *title = @"Status text";
// If previous value was empty set title twice to fix cut off issue
if (item.title.length == 0)
{
  [item setTitle:title];
}
[item setTitle:title];
```